How do I handle associations in Ruby on Rails when the JOINS involve more than 2 tables?
I'm working on a Ruby on Rails server (v6.0.1) and I'm looking for cleaner ActiveRecord joins when the join involves three tables. Here's a barebones reproduction of five models under consideration to explain the situation.
class Person
  # represents a person
end

class Company
  # represents a business entity
  has_many :shifts
end

class Employee
  # represents a person's link with a company.
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :company
end

class Shift
  # represents a daily shift that a company has
  belongs_to :company
end

class PersonShift
  # the system maps a person to the shift to indicate they showed up
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :shift
  enum status: { ongoing: "ongoing" } # and more
end

Due to the system's choice to associate a Person instead of an Employee, its now a little difficult to write a query to answer the question "How many employees currently have a shift active?" without resorting to plain SQL. While this isn't an issue by any means, I want to know if there's some way to use ActiveRecord properly to get this result.
Right now, the best I could do was this:
date = Date.today

PersonShift.ongoing.joins(:shift).joins('INNER JOIN employees on employees.company_id = shifts.company_id AND employees.person_id = person_shifts.person_id').where(shifts: { date: }).distinct.select('employees.id')

The underlying issue is that joining Employee to PersonShift involves looking at Shift and PersonShift and isn't a straightforward join. Hopefully there's some way to associate PersonShift and Employee directly via something like a has_many through?
I won't be able to modify the tables, as this is a legacy system and it would require a lot of effort to migrate that the team does not wish to put in.

The design flaw here is that the Employee model here should really be Employment or Position and the relation is one to many as one person can have many different jobs at a company. As the system is designed now there is no way to know what position a person is at during a shift. You would have to use an aggregate function like MAX to get a row from the employees table. Which employees.id do you actually want? The latest? The active one? The one that pays the least?

"it would require a lot of effort to migrate that the team does not wish to put in." At least based on the current post it does not seem like it should take too much effort to associate a PersonShift with an Employee. It seems like this could be handled by a fairly simple migration (add employee_id and back fill the relevant ids) and a before_save hook in PersonShift, to look up the employee_id as a band aid.


How many employees currently have a shift active?

Is the association between Person and Employee a one-to-one, or a one-to-many?
If it's one-to-one, then counting the number of employees and persons is actually the same thing:
Person.includes(:person_shifts).where(person_shift: {status: :ongoing, date: Date.today}).count

And add to the above: Can one person possibly be two different employees on the same day?? You haven't really explained what these two different tables are/represent, so I'd just be guessing.

Some possibilities I'm thinking are: (1) Is the Employee model poorly named, and should actually be something like JobRole? (2) Does the Person and Employee uniquely represent the same human, but split the data along some vertical like "private data" (e.g. their home address and date of birth) vs "company data" (e.g. their start date and payroll ID)? (3) Are you over-complicating the solution due to database naming confusion? Maybe someone doesn't even realise that "employee" and "person" are different database entities, so didn't realise that their question was confusing?

You will need to specify the join between Employee and PersonShift as currently there is none. Maybe you meant Person? (although that also lacks a specified relationship).   Also includes creates an OUTER JOIN and then you are querying against this join, creating an INNER JOIN. Instead just use joins.
